# wp7 datepicker and time showing display date in different format in emulator and device

Tags: windows-phone-7

When I run my app on emulator it shows date in different format MM/dd/yyyy , when i run on device it shows date in dd-MM-yyyy format . How can i forcefully display date in MM/dd/yyyy
in all the devices and emulator.

I am running this on Nokia Lumia 625.

Answer (score 0):

Just open `settings` on the emulator and configure your `language + region` settings just like you would on the phone.  Unfortunately these settings aren't saved when the emulator restarts so you'll have to set them up every time.